# Parse sentences and calculate mathematical results

Tags: ruby

Content of task:

> Given a string of words and numbers. Extract the expression including:
>
> 1. the operator: either addition or subtraction
> 2. the two numbers that we are operating on
>
> Return the result of the calculation.
>
> Example:
>
> "Panda has 48 apples and loses 4" returns 44
>
> "Jerry has 34 apples and gains 6" returns 40
>
> "loses" and "gains" are the only two words describing operators.
>
> Should be a nice little kata for you :)
>
> Note: No fruit debts nor bitten apples = The numbers are integers and
>   no negatives
>
> <sub>source: codewars.com</sub>

I want to optimise so ugly code:

```
def calculate(string)
  operator = '-' if string.split(' ').include? 'loses'
  operator = '+' if string.split(' ').include? 'gains'
  sum = 0
  count = 0
  n1 = 0
  n2 = 0
  string.split(' ').map do |s|
    if s.to_i != 0 && s.to_i.is_a?(Numeric)
      if count == 0
        n1 = s.to_i
        count += 1
      else
        n2 = s.to_i
      end
    end
  end
  n1.method(operator).(n2)
end
```

This code nice works(all tests was passed). But I don't want a large number of variables. Maybe have you some advice how to optimise this code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are manipulating text without using [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Regular expressions are a tool made specifically for text manipulation (search, delete, replace ... ) and are extremely good at their job.

The over-complication you experience comes from the use loops, conditionals and arithmetic to manipulate strings.

Here is a solution using regular expressions:

```
def text_calculation(text)
  a, b = text.split(/[^0-9]/).reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
  text.include?("gains") ? a + b : a - b
end
```

#### First line explanation

```
text.split(/[^0-9]/)
```

This [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)s the text at every character that is not a digit (`^` negates and `[0-9]` means from `0` to `9`.

The output is this list:

```
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "48", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "4"]
```

Almost what we want, we just need to remove ([`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject)) the empty strings ([`empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F)):

```
.reject(&:empty?)
```

So now we have `["48", "4"]` that we must convert to integers before we can do arithmetic on, [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) applies a function to each item of a list and [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) converts to integer so `.map(&:to_i)`

#### Second line explanation

We add if we find "gains" else subtract (`condition ? if_true : if_false` is the [Ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Ruby))

#### `.scan`

We need to find the parts of the string that match a given regex, given that the regex `/\d+\` matches all the subsequent strings of digits.

We must "find all regex matches in ruby", searching Google for such a task [lands us on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80357/match-all-occurrences-of-a-regex) reveals that [`.scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) is exactly what we can use. (The second Stack Overflow example is even about searching digits in a string!)

```
def text_calculation(text)
  a, b = text.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
  text.include?("gains") ? a + b : a - b
end
```

This code is more direct than splitting and filtering.

Comment: Why are you using code that does the same thing as `scan` but takes more resources and is less clear? Also, why the ternary? There's no point in it and it just makes it more difficult to parse.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes 1 becuase it was a previous iteration and I found scan afterwards. 2 the ternary is exactly as clear the if expression, they are conceptually identical so it makes no difference which one to use.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd prefer the explicit if because it's easier for me to read, but if you read symbols easier, fine.